# Не подсвечивается синтаксис С# на Unity (использую Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вообщем,проблема в следующем,подключил "using System;",но при использовании Convert.ToInt32 часть "convert" просто неактивна... Вроде бы все соответствующие ресурсы установил,расширение для C# тоже + dotnet-sdk-6.0.300. В самом движке Visual Studio Code выбран как редактор,по пути нет кириллицы,в остальном всё работает.

Выглядит всё это примерно так;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    private CubePos nowCube = new CubePos(0, 1, 0);
    public float cubeChangePlaceSpeed = 0.5f;

    private void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(ShowCubePlace);
    }

    IEnumenator ShowCubePlace() {

    }
}

    struct CubePos {
        public int x, y, z;

        public CubePos(int x, int y, int z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public Vector3 getVector() {
            return new Vector3(x, y, z);

        }

        public void SetVector(Vector3 pos) {
            x = Convert.ToInt32(pos.x);
            y = Convert.ToInt32(pos.y);
            z = Convert.ToInt32(pos.y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что значит часть "Convert" не активна?

Comment: На кой вам `Convert`? Пишите каст `x = (int)pos.x;`, и не мудрите.

Answer (score 0):

1. На пути к проекту есть пробелы (или в названии проекта)
2. Открываем Visual Studio -> Средства -> Получить средства и компоненты -> Прокручиваем вниз и ищем Unity -> ставим галочку и скачиваем
3. Заходим в проект -> Edit -> Preferencec -> Extrenal Tools -> выбираем Browse -> диск C:/->  Program File (*86) -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> 2019 (в вашем случае может быть другая цифра -> Community -> Common7 -> IDE -> и открываем программу devvenv
   подробнее: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8J-srV9uzw